# Embedded c - how to free allocated memory when a program crashes

Tags: c, embedded, malloc

I'm writing a simple bare-metal application on an embedded processor. As part of this application it must allocate some memory on the heap of approx 256kB, using malloc. Note: Originally this was statically allocated in main but at a certain size limit we had to move to dynamic allocation (gcc sliently failed).

The issue is - when the program runs the first time everything works. However if the processor gets reset during execution the pc returns to the start but the program memory still has the heap as it was at the previous execution. So the next time the program runs malloc fails (as malloc's allocation table from the previous run still exists and it thinks the available heap space is already allocated).

So the question is - how do I ensure malloc's table is cleared at the start of main every time I run? Is there a way I can use the location of the heap to zero out some memory (to blank the table) or alternatively get access to the list of pointers malloc has previously returned so I could free them?

Comment: The libc/c runtime startup code should be zeroing out .BSS, copying initial values into .DATA and then running C++ global constructors before jumping to main.   That should not allow the problem you're having.   If it's not doing that, look at GCC startup options:  http://cs107e.github.io/guides/gcc/

Comment: Thanks. It certainly is not doing this on this platform. Perhaps it has to do with the embedded / bare metal environment making assumptions  (wrong ones) about the memory state when it runs. All I do know for certain is the program counter us returning to the start address on reset. Looking at the link you provided, there is a glibc implementation provided for this so the standard library is an option. I'll see if I can trace what happens before main executes.

Answer (score 3):

The heap should be setup in the pre main init code. In a bare metal system there is no system call to allocate heap memory to your program. You might try getting the debugger to start at the first loaded instruction instead of main and see where it sets up the heap. It sounds like your system requires the program be reloaded on a reset to initialize the heap. What system are you using?

Comment: I'm using an embedded FPGA processor (microblaze). It's a gcc based system. The heap location varies with the executable size as it starts at the end of of the code section - so this location varies as the prpgram is developed. Id like a solution that is robust/independent of program size. My current workaround for all this is not 'clean' as I've basically not used malloc and set my pointer manually to a location well beyond where the heap normally begins - but I'm sure SO can come up with a much better approach.

Comment: Reloading of the .elf is not possible in the environment this is used - the elf is embedded in the bitstream which is only loaded once.

Comment: @JohnMcGrath you don't need to reload the elf to rerun the startup code.

Comment: This is what id expect also. It would seem there is no start-up code related to zeroing the heap/malloc data.

Answer (score 2):

There is a topic here for exactly this issue:

[Microblaze (no OS) - heap not clean after reset](https://support.xilinx.com/s/question/0D52E00006hpcuDSAQ/microblaze-no-os-heap-not-clean-after-reset)

Unfortunately no answer but you are not the first to hit this. I think you have to step through from load in the debugger and see where the init code sets the heap pointer.

Comment: Thanks. That is the same issue, and well described - and I assumed a solution would look something like : 1) find where malloc keeps it's allocation table, 2) get the list of allocated items (one in this case) and 3) call free on it. So this should be possible, the question is how? I think SO is better than that other forum as the solution is a general question of gcc/malloc behaviour rather than anything particularly processor implementation specific (even if the issue arising in the first place is)

Comment: That's not bare metal. Anyone asking "where does x store the heap" is not writing bare metal, they are writing on top of some spoon-fed abstraction layer. In bare metal applications _the programmer_ writes the linker script, no one else. If the CRT does not clear the heap, then add the code for it. One trivial call to memset, once you have figured out the linker names - or use hardcoded addresses even.

Answer (score -1):

What on earth are you doing?

- At CPU reset you can't rely on *anything*, you need to initialize *everything* in the MCU, including stack and RAM setup. This is true for every microcontroller program ever written, bare metal ones in particular. In case you for some reason is using a heap, you need to zero-out the memory before use.
- Using malloc on a bare metal embedded system simply does not make sense. Where you had static .data/.bss variables before, you have a static heap segment instead. The heap solves no problem, it just hides the problem under the carpet.

  The main thing here is: either you have enough memory to cover the worst case, or you don't. Period. [See this](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/171257/realloc-wasting-lots-of-space-in-my-mcu/171581#171581). Or if you are writing a program which is allowed to fail and bug out unexpectedly, you can ignore this.

Comment: As I said in the original post I'm allocating a single buffer as this was working around an issue where allocating it statically worked fine until that buffer size was ~256kb. As to why allocating it statically failed after a certain size is another post entirely. In addition - there is only one allocation, all other buffer are smaller and statically allocated. I agree at cpu reset everything should be initialized, but surely this is the job of the init code before main in the elf - not each developer! Given it appears to not init the heap correctly it would indicate a bug in that unit code.

Comment: @JohnMcGrath On bare metal, everything is the programmer's responsibility - in particularly the linker script. Perhaps the heap is not set to be zero-out, or perhaps the "CRT" init code makes assumptions about the heap. Relying on such start-up code to be correct is often dangerous. Regardless, it is simple to work-around, just call memset on the whole heap before you call malloc.

Comment: thanks - memset on the heap is what I was looking for. I agree it does sound like the crt init is making assumptions, which is dangerous. I'll try confirm this by seeing what happens before main. Regarding responsibility - to me if malloc is supported by the embedded environment then it's a bug in the implementation if it does not init correctly with unknown mem contents. Ultimate responsibility lies with the developer of course - but the environment in embedded should be built on solid foundations too!

Comment: @JohnMcGrath There may be some project-specific setting that you have to enable to use the heap. First of all, make sure it is present as `.heap` or some such in the linker script - otherwise all bets are off.

Comment: Thanks - yes I've checked that. There is a heap section. I was considering manually specifying that section start address in the linker script to have a fixed location of the pointer to the allocated memory block, but i think the idea of initializing the heap at the start is much cleaner and the correct general solution.